# Are zones 'fixed' at a certain power level or do they scale at all?

Tags: assassins-creed-valhalla

I've tried to look into this and most every answer gives a soft or even a firm 'no', there is no level scaling. Zones have a suggested power level (SPL) and a fixed difficulty that's supposed to make a reasonable challenge at that power level.

But I just encountered something that makes me question it.

I'm on my first play through and I really want to face a reasonable challenge throughout. Rather than adjusting the combat difficulty, I've just been gating my own power growth by no spending points. I've finished half the zones in England and chasing after every map marker (mystery, artifact and treasure) had started putting my level way over the top. So I stopped spending my skill points as I got them and even refunded some to go back down to a zone's suggested level.

Then I came across some enemies that I couldn't beat and beefed up my power level in response to let me advance without having to come back later. Details in the spoiler tag:

> First was Steinnbjorn in Jotunheim. Without realizing it, I was at ~165 when Jotunheim was showing up as SPL 190. Then I saw Steinnbjorn at SPL 400, tried it, got stomped, spent skills up to 190, tried it again, got stomped and then went on to finish the Jotunheim arc.
>  After that, I returned to Asgard to finish up the dream-within-a-dream narrative. The quest and zone map were saying SPL 90, same as the first time through Asgard. But when I faced the ever-growing Fenrir, it said his SPL was 280. After getting gnawed on by his burrow attack and 1-shot killed a few too many times, I spent skills up to 230 and beat him.

So long story short, I was at Power Level 230 before getting back to the southern England story line.

Alternate question title:

### Is Suthsexe supposed to be 'skull' difficulty?

I committed to Suthsexe at the alliance map and travelled down there via the Lunden docks. After I was in zone for a bit, I remembered my Power Level 230 was 70 over the suggested 160. So I refunded a bunch of skill points.

Then I noticed every enemy had a red skull icon next to their health and stun bars and took about twice as many hits as enemies had previously.

So is Suthsexe supposed to be way harder than previous zones when done 'on level'? Or did I trip some scaling mechanism into juicing up the enemies there before nerfing myself?

Comment: "Boss" opponents in a zone can be considerably higher than the suggested level of the area. This is like that even right at the start when you do not have many skill points (even unspent) or power levels. The power level of these bosses does not seem to change. I do not know about the monster in the spoiler though.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, the game does increase the power level of enemies you are facing based upon your total – spent and unspent – skill points.

For the last few zones in the main story arc – Snotingham, Hordafylke and Hamptunshire, I have entered with around 100 unspent skill points. Each time, the first regular enemies I face have a red dot next to their health bars indicating they have significantly more difficulty than my current spent skill points. The first boss enemy – typically a zealot, legendary animal, or lost vikingr – I faced would have a suggested power level next to their health bars exactly equal to my total skill points.

In other words, **the 'Suggested Power Level' for a zone is really just a minimum** level. If you have more spent skills than that power level, the game will increase the stats of the enemies you are facing.

It's worth reiterating that the power level mechanic is only based upon skill point. Gear upgrades, runes, skill + equipment synergies (e.g. wearing all Raven aligned gear with no skill points spent in the Raven skill tree), and abilities are ignored and can all serve to make the zone you're in harder or easier.

Comment: What was your level scaling setting? That your unspent skill points have an impact is new to me, but with level scaling you can make "normal" zone enemies much stronger than the suggested power level (based on your power level).

Comment: I just discovered the level scaling setting a few days ago.It was set to 'default' at the time, which is described as enemies being scaled up to at least 'your power level - 30'. I changed it to the 'your level + 30' setting, and now every zone and every enemy is consistently a red skull.

Comment: Also in my experience the level/difficulty scaling is based on spent and unspent skill points, in contrast to just the power level. I had a lot of unspent skill points and even above power level 200 I had lots of non-boss skull level opponents. It improved after I spent my around 50 unspent skill points.